# Sitecore PowerShell 6.0 Console on Sitecore 9.3 does not work

Tags: powershell-extensions

I just installed Sitecore 9.3 Standalone XP locally. After rebuilding the link databases and indexes; I did install the Sitecore PowerShell 6.0 package. I could not make the PowerShell console work. The other features of Sitecore PowerShell are working fine. Also, the SPE log files does not provide any relevant information. 
It does not pass the "Elevate Session State".

[image]

Below is the entire SPE log file.

```
    16356 21:58:02 INFO  Executing PsSitecoreItemProvider5.Start(providerInfo='Sitecore')
7580 21:58:02 INFO  Script item set to master:\system\Modules\PowerShell\Script Library\SPE\Reporting\Content Reports\Reports\Solution Audit\Make good use of inheritance in ScriptSession $scriptSession$|aswqveouteanwpsgbcjk35fl|ff10be73-bb38-4bf0-b689-027eb944c6fd.
ManagedPoolThread #3 21:58:02 INFO  Executing a script in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|aswqveouteanwpsgbcjk35fl|ff10be73-bb38-4bf0-b689-027eb944c6fd'.
21820 21:58:53 WARN  Session state elevated for 'Console' by user: sitecore\Admin
21796 22:03:54 WARN  Session state elevation expired for 'Console' for user: sitecore\Admin
21516 22:06:56 WARN  Session state elevated for 'Console' by user: sitecore\Admin
22944 22:11:56 WARN  Session state elevation expired for 'Console' for user: sitecore\Admin
21636 22:15:26 WARN  Session state elevated for 'Console' by user: sitecore\Admin
```

Did anybody have the same issue?

Comment: can you try by enabling `Cognifide.PowerShell.IdentityServer.config` by removing disable from it?

Comment: Thanks "Mahendra Shekhawat" and "Michael West", this solved the issue. However, the file name in Sitecore 9.3 is different. App_Config\Include\Spe\Spe.IdentityServer.config